# What's the right way to handle action state in the layout page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What I mean is this: I've got a layout page that shows a *different* favicon depending on what action is being invoked.  So I've got some code in the layout that looks like this:

```
<link href="/images/favicon/@(AmbientPage.ShortName).ico" type="image/ico" rel="icon" />
```

The `AmbientPage` variable is a global value that's set in the `Index` action, and read by the layout file, which dynamically writes the icon filename for whatever page was requested.  This seems really kludgy to me, but I'm not seeing a great way around it either.

What do you do when the Layout page needs to know something that happened in the action?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would use a child action or section to avoid having logics in the layout page. So in the case above, other ways of doing it would be passing the name of the current page to an child action and let child action determine what icon/action to use.

It would be something like:

```
  @Html.Action("Icon", "Default", new { @ViewContext.RouteData["Action"] })
```

Or using an section, in layout page, you add the following code

```
  //true since they all required to have an icon
    @RenderSection("Icon", true)
```

then in your view you just do

```
@section Icon{
     <link href="/images/favicon/currentpage.ico" type="image/ico" rel="icon" />
 }
```

Personally, I would suggest you to use the section approach to make the code "less dependent" on each other